# How to access files in the build directory for Docker within the container?

Tags: bash, docker

I have a file `python-setup.py` in the root directory in which the `Dockerfile` lives and forms the basis for the container.

Here is the beginning of the `Dockerfile`

```
from ubuntu:20.04
RUN echo "HOME is $HOME"
ADD ./setup-python.sh $HOME/
RUN cd $HOME && ./setup-python.sh
```

Why does this not work?  The result is:

```
> [4/4] RUN cd $HOME && ./setup-python.sh:
#8 0.243 /bin/sh: 1: ./setup-python.sh: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `WORKDIR` plus `COPY` gets it done:

```
from ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR .
RUN echo "HOME is $HOME"
COPY  ./setup-python.sh .

RUN ./setup-python.sh
```